# Better interactive TeX shell

Tags: texlive, plain-tex

I'm using the command-line interactive TeX shell on Linux, accessible via the `tex` command (Artix, package texlive-bin 2022.62885-3, available at https://tug.org/texlive). I've found it a very helpful utility for testing out how control sequences interact with each other. The use of it is simple and involves typing in plain TeX commands and pressing Enter; I can use it to `\show` the meaning of commands or typeset to a .dvi file and view it later.

I have noticed however that it does not allow using the up and down arrow keys to access previous commands, instead printing escape sequences to the prompt when these keys are pressed.

I would be very happy with a command line utility exactly like the texlive `tex` command, but with the ability to use the arrow keys for navigating through the history, so I don't have to retype or copy and paste repeated commands. Does something like this exist?

Comment: Possibly system-specific. On my system (Termux app on Android, which is a Linux command-line interface, possibly based on Debian, using BASH shell) I do get previous commands when I use the up/down arrows in BASH.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for noting. I do not often get strange terminal issues with interpreters. I use zsh for my login shell but if I switch to bash or to a TTY (or both) the TeX shell does the same thing in all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`rlwrap`](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap). The package is available in pretty much every distro ([here's the package for Arch](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/rlwrap/), which I think should also work for Artix). Prefixing a command with `rlwrap` makes it support arrow keys, history, etc. For TeX specifically, the command that you want is probably

```bash
rlwrap pdftex '\relax'
```

(replace with `pdftex` with `pdflatex`, `luatex`, etc. as desired)

Comment: Thanks, that is one great command there!